# Frontend angular project not working with Spring boot project after changes to context root

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project that has an angular app integrated into it. The angular is packed into a jar and is made available to the application in the application jar.

The project structure is more or less like this:

[image]

It works fine when the context-root is "/". But if I make modifications to the context root from "/" to "/project1" in spring boot configuration file I am no more able to access the frontend.

Could anyone provide any hint how I could fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a base tag to the head of your index.html

```
<base href="/project1/">
```

Link to the docs for further explanation if needed: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href

Answer (score 0):

Why would you change it? Need for information about this

Comment: I am just trying to do some experiments.

Comment: Maybe that's the result of your experiments then

Comment: Please comment only if you have a solution to the problem :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this is because your client app is packaged as a jar, and will thus not register any changes made to the root context.